# Falcon API - check if the server is running

Tags: python, falconframework

I have built a very simple API in Falcon that post results of my machine learning model. See below:

```py
import falcon
import heureka_predikce


class MLmodel:
    def on_post(self, req, resp):

        reg_list = req.media
        response_list = []

        for vstup in reg_list:
            response_list.append(heureka_predikce.heureka_predikuj(vstup))

        resp.text = response_list
        resp.status = falcon.HTTP_OK


my_model = MLmodel()

app = application = falcon.API()
app.add_route("/predictionApi/v1/predict", my_model)
```

But I would like to check if the server is running. That is, I would like to include some new method into `MLmodel` that does a "health check". I am a beginner with APIs, but is there a recommended way, how to do this? I think that it should be relatively easy, but I cannot find anything myself... Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To check if server is up and running, usually what we do is send a request at an endpoint and server will return something indicating that it's working.

As you said you will need to add a method in `MLmodel` for the same reason, it can be done but it's not the recommended way as your `MLmodel` is handling `predict` endpoint.

To do a health check, you can create a new endpoint with new class which will accept a `get` request and will respond you as soon it is invoked.

For Ex.:

```
class Ping:
    def on_get(self, req, resp):
        resp.text = "pong"
        resp.status = falcon.HTTP_OK
```

And then just add route for same resource using:
`app.add_route("/predictionApi/v1/ping", Ping())`

Now for each ping request, you will get pong response.

Comment: thanks! Is the `req` attribute in `on_get` necessary?

Comment: Don't know for sure, but it must be! Cause this structure of method is predefined by Falcon library, like an abstract method with required parameters. But you can try removing it and see what happens! Lemme know if it's other way around.. thanks